# Printing tensorflow variable seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to print a tensor attns in tensorflow seq2seq code. [Seq2Seq.py](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_ios/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L557)

I tried:

```
tf.Print(attns, [attns])
```

but it prints nothing.

I tried

```
sess = tf.Session() 
sess.run(attns) or attns.eval()
```

I this case it throws:  InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

I have also tried using sess.run()

```
sess = tf.get_default_session()
aa = sess.run(attns)
```

In this case sess object is None.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.Print` is not a "classic" operational instruction, since those are not executed in symbolic, graph-based code. What is needed instead is a specific node in the computation graph that will then be triggered whenever your computations "passes" that node.

This is exactly what tf.Print does. It creates a "wrapper" node around any other node by creating an identity operation that, when triggered, prints the value of a list of tensors.

The first argument of [this print function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/debugging_operations#Print), `input_` (or `attns` in your case) is the wrapped node, and `data` (or `[attns]` in your case) is the list of tensors to be printed.

What you therefore want to do is to add this line:

```
attns = tf.Print(attns, [attns])
```

Here, `attns` is assigned a print wrapper identity operation on `attns` - so the tensor `attns` has exactly the same behavior, except that when it is computed, it will also print `[attns]`.

Comment: When I am trying this, it is throwing value error at seq2seq.py#L560 because of dimension mismatch. I tried removing tf.Print and it works fine. I am loading a trained model, in case it matters. Although it still prints nothing.

Comment: @p.j weird. Could you update your comment for the exact error? (not the full trace, but the name of the tensor mismatching, and the dimensions given and expected)